# Streaming from CSV files with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-csv

I am trying to use Spark Streaming to collect data from CSV files located on NFS.
The code I have is very simple, and so far I have been running it only in spark-shell, but even there I am running into some issues.

I am running spark-shell with a standalone Spark master with 6 workers, and passing the following arguments to spark-shell:

--master spark://master.host:7077 --num-executors 3 --conf spark.cores.max=10

This is the code:

```
val schema = spark.read.option("header", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").csv("/nfs/files_to_collect/schema/schema.csv").schema
val data = spark.readStream.option("header", true).schema(schema).csv("/nfs/files_to_collect/jobs/jobs*")
val query = data.writeStream.format("console").start()
```

There are 2 files in that NFS path, each about 200MB in size.
When I call writeStream, I get the following warning:

"17/11/13 22:56:31 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 2 contains a task of very large size (106402 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB."

Looking in the Spark master UI, I see that only one executor was used - four tasks were created, each reading ~50% of each CSV file.

My questions are:

1) The more files there are in the NFS path, the more memory the driver seems to need - with 2 files, it would crash until I increased its memory to 2g. With 4 files it needs no less than 8g. What is the driver doing that it needs so much memory?

2) How do I control the parallelism of reading the CSV files? I noticed that the more files there are, the more tasks are created, but is it possible to control this manually?

Comment: Have you got any solutions for this .. ? am facing same issue